# How to update App version of a NativeScript Angular app?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am looking for a possible ways to update/set App Versions of my NativeScript Angular app. I found few ways but, I was not able to successfully update my app to newer versions.

I used this [set-version](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-set-version/) plugin but could not get it to work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to update your Angular version in your App, read this. It is the official documentation. You can choose your current version and the latest version you want and appear the steps you need to follow.

https://update.angular.io/